# How to add left side category sorting?

Tags: magento-1.7

Hi all I'm a newbie to Magento.

My question is how can I add left category sorting in the product list?

Just like this:

[image: Sample]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an in-built feature in Magento. Go to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Layered Navigation.` This section allows you to configure the information such as product count, price limit.

[image]

> EDIT:

If you go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` under the `Front-end Properties` section you can set `Use In Layered Navigation` drop down to `filterable`. Then those attributes will be visible in front-end layered navigation.

Comment: When I try it and "Save Config", nothing happen.

Comment: @Enalds: I updated the answer. try it